# Type Error -How should be the index in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def __init__(self, dictionary_paths):
    files = [open(path, 'r') for path in dictionary_paths]
    dictionaries = [yaml.load(dict_file) for dict_file in files]
    map(lambda x: x.close(), files)
    self.dictionary = {}
    self.max_key_size = 0
    for curr_dict in dictionaries:
        for key in curr_dict:
            if key in self.dictionary:
                self.dictionary[key].extend(curr_dict[key])
            else:
                self.dictionary[key] = curr_dict[key]
                self.max_key_size = max(self.max_key_size, len(key))
    self.dictionary[key] = curr_dict[key]
```

results in

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is curr_dict? And what is dictionary? and what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `curr_dict` is a string and not a dict, despite what its name implies:

```
In [6]: 'abc'['x']

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```